# How to create a div with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, button

Morning :)

Im trying to create a div everytime a push one button with jQuery.

```
$('#button_submit').click(function() 
{
//create a div inside a already existing div (<div id="save"></div>) with this parametres:
/*
<h3>Title</h3>
<div>
<p>
Some text
</p>
</div>
*/
}

<div id="save"></div>
```

Any help? :) Cheers

EDIT:

```
//newArray is defined.
$("<button id=saved>").click(function() {
drawChart.apply(null, newArray);
}).text("click me")
```

this button should be inside the new div too. Can I easly integrate ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#button_submit').click(function(){
$('<h3>Title</h3><div><p>Some text</p></div>').appendTo('#save');
});
```

This creates what you want inside Save

**Edit for update**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      function newFunction(){ 

         /*This is the new function*/

      }

$('#button_submit').click(function(){
        $('<h3>Title</h3><div><p>Some text</p></div><input type="button" value="saved" id="saved" onclick="newFunction()"/>').appendTo('#save');
      });
});
```

Comment: So you want a button in the newly created div to do the same thing?

Comment: No, the button will make something else

Comment: Hm, seems not. Because button should keep `drawChart.apply(null, newArray)`

Comment: You could add drawChart.apply(null,newArray) to the newFunction()

Comment: try changing the div to input with type="button"

Comment: wrapped the functions with document.ready so it adds the function on window load. Updated the answer

Comment: This question is solved, ive another question related to this but I will open a new one, thanks :)

Comment: Weird, i dont think so, try logging out and in

Comment: `Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See http://goo.gl/C1Kwu to learn more.`I think its because -5 votes.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using show()-hide() mechanism to achieve whatever it is you are trying.

Put the markup in the original html, but make it "display:none". when you need to "add" it to the page - "show()" it. It's almost always superior and cleaner. This way you don't need to construct divs with javascript.

But if you must add an element dynamically, use [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

Edit:

I'm not really sure what is your structure, but if you need to have the button inside consider these options:

1. put another button in the original markup (if you adhere to my advice about using show()-hide())
2. position the button absolutely and just move it where you want
3. use jquery [appendTo](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/)

note that some of these options may not be suitable, depending on the rest of your markup.